Is there a way in react-flow/dagre to move my home node to the bottom of the flow chart?
I'm currently working on a project to implement react-flow using dagre to automate the layout and I'm running into an issue where the "Home Node" is on the left hand side, instead of the bottom, as everything should flow into it.
Link to React code sandbox
Any help appreciated
Current Layout

Desired Layout

